# Creating URL in Dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo

Is there a function in Dojo that lets you specify URL parameters that I can take to `window.open()`?

e.g. I'm looking for a function like `someDojoFunction()` below.

```
window.open(someDojoFunction("stackoverflow.com", "param1", 100,  "param2", 200));
```

Sure, it would be trivial to write a function like that, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel and I want to do it dojo way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[There is something like that available](http://svn.dojotoolkit.org/dojoc/mwilcox/util/Window.js).

BTW, if you want access to an arbitrary list of arguments like that, look into the `arguments` object of every function.

Comment: Plus one for mentioning my widget :)